Missing /usr/bin/python3
I'm missing the python3 binary in /usr/bin/.
which python3 outputs /home/d4rkc10ud/anaconda3/bin/python3
sudo apt install python3 outputs python3 is already the newest version (3.12.3-0ubuntu1).
sudo apt install python3-dev outputs python3-dev is already the newest version (3.12.3-0ubuntu1).
A python3 file exists in /usr/local/bin that links to a python3.12 file in the same directory.
I'm running Kubuntu 24.04 on my machine. I'd really appreciate any help.
UPDATE:
file /usr/bin/python3 outputs /usr/bin/python3: broken symbolic link to python3.12
Maybe creating a symbolic link from /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/local/bin/python3.12 would help? I'm fairly new to linux so I'm afraid to just try it and mess things up more.

Please provide the backstory in detail. What did you do with Python on your machine to get to this state? Please include all commands you ran. Thanks.

I wanted to do a fresh reinstall of python3 on my system a month and a half back. I think I may have messed it up then. I don't have the commands I used back then but I did reinstall python3 using anaconda which I think only did a local install of python3.

You shouldn't mess with the default Python version - this may break your installation. There are countless questions here about ruined systems because users messed with Python.

I believe I have the same issue as another user: Cannot reinstall ubuntu desktop python3-minimal issue

Is there a way I can reinstall the system wide python3 installation without a fresh OS install? I'd like to preserve the already installed packages and files.

You could try sudo apt install --reinstall --fix-broken python3. Please report if it works as expected. See man apt-get for useful options.

It says
Errors were encountered while processing: python3-minimal
It mentions py3compile: not found which seems to depend on #! /usr/bin/python3

Yes this is why the situation is more difficult than expected. I don't know a solid fix to this. Hopefully someone else can chime in..

Alright, thank you for your help though!

Some essential basic functionality in Ubuntu (for example the terminal) depends on having the default Python 3 version installed. update-alternatives, is it generally usable?

I have not tested this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1522121/1066942

@karel I'm not sure the dupe is spot on - but I gave it a shot. Might vote to reopen here, since the method is very specific to version and architecture (since apt can't be used).

Should I try ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-optimizations to install python from source into /usr/bin/?
